# Compiling C++ code using __float128

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I'm trying to use `__float128` in my C++ program.

However I'm in trouble with compiling it.

Here is simple c++ code (test.cc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <quadmath.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  __float128 r=0.0q;
  __float128 exp_d = expq(12.45q);

  cout << "r=" << (double)r << endl;
  cout << "exp_d=" << (double)exp_d << endl;
}
```

And I compile this code with

`g++ test.cc -lquadmath -std=c++11`

which comes with following error

`error:unable to find numeric literal operator 'operateor"" q'`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check in `quadmath.h` for `operator "" q(__float128)` - that's what it says is missing.  If there are any `#if`/`#endif` conditions on the inclusion of the operator, consider whether/why you might be hitting the wrong branch.  Where did you read that the `q` suffix was even provided?  Separately, quite a few websites suggest using `extern "C" { #include <quadmath.h> }` - might be necessary for linking, depending on how old your quadmath library version is.

Comment: I tried `extern "C" { #include <quadmath.h> }`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I avoided this compile error using [`strtoflt128()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/strtoflt128.html#strtoflt128), but I'm still curious how to resolve this compile error.

Comment: The `q` literal suffix is an extension, `-std=c++11` disables it. [Compile with `-std=gnu++11`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54be5e202a7906ad).

Comment: Now I am really surprised where people get the idea for 128 bit floats from, given that SIMD floats are 80 bits wide. Is there any 128 bit float hardware support on x86/x64?

Comment: @user2225104 where do you get the idea that "SIMD floats are 80 bits wide"? There is hardware support on s390. But there is nothing wrong with a software implementation on x86.

Comment: @MarcGlisse https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly

Comment: @user2225104 Hint: x87 handles 80 bit floating-point numbers and no simd (let's ignore MMX) while sse has simd but doesn't handle floating-point numbers with more than 64 bits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gcc-5 prints this helpful additional note:

> note: use `-std=gnu++11` or `-fext-numeric-literals` to enable more built-in suffixes

Answer (score 2):

As I commented earlier, I think your problem is that the C++11 literal handling is pre-empting the GCC-specific C extension that handles the `q` suffix.  Try providing a C++11 operator - as below:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C"
{
    #include <quadmath.h>
}

__float128 operator ""q(const char* p)
{
    return strtoflt128(p, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    __float128 x = expq(282.49q);
    char buffer[128];
    quadmath_snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%.36Qg\n", x);
    std::cout << buffer << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `strtoflt128` isn't `constexpr` (it's a C function!). Also you don't need `extern "C"` since it's already present in the header.