# ERROR: unknown type name '__float128' while compiling stdlib.h

Tags: c, gcc, uclibc, libgc

Trying to compile tcpdump package with uClibc
Getting error while compiling stdlib.h
ERROR: unknown type name '__float128' while compiling stdlib.h
Unable to identify why the error is.
I don't know whether i am missing any dependencies.

Comment: What do you mean with "compiling stdlib.h"? Normally headers are not compiled standalone. It would also help a lot if you provide your toolchain

Comment: Are you sure this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404555/compiling-c-code-using-float128 ?

Comment: @John uClibc and tdpdump have nothing to do with C++

Comment: @Ruslan It's too late now, isn't it.. OP edited the question adding those details after my comment. Though, the OP should try compiling the package with -std=gnu11

Comment: @John sorry, didn't notice the fact of change.